# How can I delete unused measures in cube without breaking pbix?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, cube, ssas-tabular

I have 3 .pbix  files that consume live from a SSAS cube.

The .bim cube has thousands of measures (most of them not used at all).

My goal is to delete the unused measures in the .bim (without breaking any visual in the .pbix).

Is there a way of opening the 3 .pbix and extracting all the measures/columns used? (or a way of seeing in the .bim which measures are unused?

Ps: each .pbix has 15 pages, so its hard to do it manually.

Comment: You'll need a 3rd party tool like Power BI Helper, which should you an over view on what is and isnt used https://powerbihelper.org/

Answer (score 0):

As @Jon says, you need an external tool for this analysis. [Power BI Helper](https://powerbihelper.org/) is one, but I find it slow and not as thorough as [Measure Killer](https://en.brunner.bi/measurekiller). Last I knew, you have to run Measure Killer separately on each .pbix and combine the results, though they had your use case on their roadmap. If you find that one report has all the fields used by the other two (or force it that way), Measure Killer will do the deletes for you.

Here's a view of an exported Excel report from Measure Killer:

[image: Measure Killer report]

**Columns in report**

- Name
- Type
- Table
- Is used
- Expression
- Used in calculations
- Used on visuals in page(s)
- Used on filters in page(s)
- Used on conditional formatting in page(s)
- Used on filters for the whole page(s)
- Used on filters all page(s)
- Used on M Expressions in
- Others
- IsCalendar
- ColSize